# T-SQL join to get both mated and non mated start and stop records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a poorly designed table that I did not design and cannot fix/change because a 3rd party blackberry app that writes to it.  The meat is that there is a start record and a stop record for tracking events with NO connection or validation that there is a match.  The blackberry app does nothing to tie these records together. I have tried to create a join on its self and create temp tables with the begin and one with the end to full outer join them. The problem is that I have duplicate entries were the entry should be marked as having no mate. Existing data has rows with no mate on both the start and end records. I have searched SO for answers and I found some close answers that have led me this far. I know its a long post, sorry for that.

There is a ***single*** table that surprisingly has a primary key. There is no pivot/intersection table. Structure is

```
ID (int PK)
activityType varchar
beginEnd varchar ('begin' or 'end')
businessKey varchar nullable
date DATETIME
technician varchar
```

The following columns are in the table as well, but are nullable, and not important to the query.

```
dateSubmitted DATETIME
gpsLatitude float
gpsLongitude float
note varchar
odometer int
```

---

The query that I have now that still leaves dupes: Showing and sorting ID and EndID are for debugging only

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME
DECLARE @DateTo DATETIME
SET @DateFrom='20101101'
SET @DateTo='20101102'
DECLARE @Incomplete VARCHAR(15)
SET @Incomplete = 'Incomplete'

DECLARE @StartEvents TABLE
(
[id] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
[activityType] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[beginEnd] [varchar](255) NULL,
[businessKey] [varchar](255) NULL,
[date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[dateSubmitted] [datetime] NULL,
[gpsLatitude] [float] NULL,
[gpsLongitude] [float] NULL,
[note] [varchar](255) NULL,
[odometer] [int] NULL,
[technician] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
)

INSERT     @StartEvents
       ([ID],[activityType],[beginEnd],[businessKey],[date],[dateSubmitted],[gpsLatitude]
            ,[gpsLongitude],[note],[odometer],[technician])
SELECT      *
FROM        dbo.TimeEntry
WHERE 
[date] between @DateFrom AND @DateTo
AND beginEnd = 'Begin'
--AND [technician] = 'FRED'
ORDER by technician
------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @EndEvents TABLE
(
[id] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
[activityType] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[beginEnd] [varchar](255) NULL,
[businessKey] [varchar](255) NULL,
[date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[dateSubmitted] [datetime] NULL,
[gpsLatitude] [float] NULL,
[gpsLongitude] [float] NULL,
[note] [varchar](255) NULL,
[odometer] [int] NULL,
[technician] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
)

INSERT     @EndEvents
       ([ID],[activityType],[beginEnd],[businessKey],[date],[dateSubmitted],[gpsLatitude]
            ,[gpsLongitude],[note],[odometer],[technician])
SELECT      *
FROM        dbo.TimeEntry
WHERE 
[date] between @DateFrom AND @DateTo AND
beginEnd = 'End'
--AND [technician] = 'FRED'
ORDER by technician

-- And then a conventional SELECT
SELECT     
StartEvents.id 
,EndEvents.id AS EndID
,COALESCE(
    StartEvents.activityType ,EndEvents.activityType ,'Not Available'
    ) AS ActivityType
--,StartEvents.beginEnd as [Begin] 
--,EndEvents.beginEnd AS [End]
,COALESCE (
    convert(VARCHAR(12), StartEvents.[date], 103), 
    convert(VARCHAR(12), EndEvents.[date], 103), @Incomplete
    ) as [Event Date] 
,COALESCE (
    convert(VARCHAR(12), EndEvents.[date], 103), @Incomplete 
    ) as [End Date] 
,COALESCE(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5) , StartEvents.dateSubmitted , 108) , @Incomplete
        ) AS StartTime
,COALESCE(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5) , EndEvents.dateSubmitted , 108) , @Incomplete
        ) AS EndTime
,COALESCE(
    StartEvents.note, EndEvents.note, ''
    ) as [Note]
,COALESCE(
    StartEvents.technician,EndEvents.technician,'Not Available'
    ) AS Technician 

FROM         
@StartEvents As StartEvents 

FULL OUTER JOIN

@EndEvents AS EndEvents ON 
StartEvents.technician = EndEvents.technician AND 
StartEvents.businessKey = EndEvents.businessKey AND 
StartEvents.activityType = EndEvents.activityType 
AND convert(VARCHAR(12), StartEvents.[date], 103) = convert(VARCHAR(12), EndEvents.[date], 103) 

-- WHERE 
    --StartEvents.[date] between @DateFrom AND @DateTo OR 
    --StartEvents.[dateSubmitted] between @DateFrom AND @DateTo 
ORDER BY 
    StartEvents.Technician,
    ID,ENDID
```

---

DATA:

```
id,activityType,beginEnd,businessKey,date,dateSubmitted,gpsLatitude,gpsLongitude,note,odometer,technician
23569,Standby,Begin,,2010-11-01 08:00:13.000,2010-11-01 08:26:45.533,34.139,-77.895,#1140,28766,barthur@fubar.com
23570,Travel,Begin,00100228002,2010-11-01 07:00:44.000,2010-11-01 08:34:15.370,35.0634,-80.7668,,18706,creneau@fubar.com
23571,Standby,End,,2010-11-01 08:30:08.000,2010-11-01 08:35:20.463,34.0918,-77.9002,#1140,28766,barthur@fubar.com
23572,Travel,Begin,00100226488,2010-11-01 08:30:41.000,2010-11-01 08:36:56.420,34.0918,-77.9002,,28766,barthur@fubar.com
23573,Travel,End,00100226488,2010-11-01 08:45:00.000,2010-11-01 08:44:15.553,34.0918,-77.9002,,28768,barthur@fubar.com
23574,OnSite,Begin,00100226488,2010-11-01 08:45:41.000,2010-11-01 09:24:23.943,34.0918,-77.9002,,0,barthur@fubar.com
23575,OnSite,End,00100226488,2010-11-01 09:30:10.000,2010-11-01 09:33:19.953,34.0918,-77.9002,,28768,barthur@fubar.com
23576,Travel,Begin,00100228137,2010-11-01 09:30:20.000,2010-11-01 09:34:57.330,34.0918,-77.9002,,28768,barthur@fubar.com
23577,Travel,End,00100228137,2010-11-01 09:45:51.000,2010-11-01 09:42:39.230,34.0918,-77.9002,,28771,barthur@fubar.com
23578,Travel,Begin,00100228138,2010-11-01 09:00:23.000,2010-11-01 09:58:22.857,34.9827,-80.5365,,18749,creneau@fubar.com
23579,OnSite,Begin,00100228137,2010-11-01 09:45:47.000,2010-11-01 10:41:10.563,34.139,-77.895,,0,barthur@fubar.com
23580,OnSite,End,00100228137,2010-11-01 10:45:43.000,2010-11-01 11:09:14.393,34.139,-77.895,,28771,barthur@fubar.com
23581,OnSite,Begin,00100228142,2010-11-01 10:45:42.000,2010-11-01 11:29:26.447,34.139,-77.895,#1015,28771,barthur@fubar.com
23582,OnSite,End,00100228142,2010-11-01 11:15:18.000,2010-11-01 11:55:28.603,34.139,-77.895,#1015,28771,barthur@fubar.com
23583,Travel,Begin,,2010-11-01 11:15:06.000,2010-11-01 11:56:01.633,34.139,-77.895,"#1142 Fuel, #1154 Tickets",28771,barthur@fubar.com
23584,Travel,End,,2010-11-01 12:00:47.000,2010-11-01 12:07:54.867,34.139,-77.895,"#1154, #1142",28774,barthur@fubar.com
23585,Travel,End,,2010-11-01 12:00:47.000,2010-11-01 12:07:55.087,34.139,-77.895,"#1154, #1142",28774,barthur@fubar.com
23586,Break,Begin,,2010-11-01 12:00:26.000,2010-11-01 12:08:06.007,34.139,-77.895,#1153,28774,barthur@fubar.com
23587,Travel,End,,2010-11-01 12:00:47.000,2010-11-01 12:08:06.040,34.139,-77.895,"#1154, #1142",28774,barthur@fubar.com
23588,Break,Begin,,2010-11-01 12:00:26.000,2010-11-01 12:08:06.070,34.139,-77.895,#1153,28774,barthur@fubar.com
23589,Travel,End,,2010-11-01 12:00:47.000,2010-11-01 12:16:02.673,34.139,-77.895,"#1154, #1142",28774,barthur@fubar.com
23590,Travel,End,,2010-11-01 12:00:47.000,2010-11-01 12:16:14.220,34.139,-77.895,"#1154, #1142",28774,barthur@fubar.com
23591,Travel,Begin,00100228000,2010-11-01 11:45:19.000,2010-11-01 12:35:46.363,35.0634,-80.7668,,18760,creneau@fubar.com
23592,Travel,Begin,00100227980,2010-11-01 13:15:14.000,2010-11-01 13:58:51.050,34.0918,-77.9002,,28774,barthur@fubar.com
23593,Travel,Begin,00100227980,2010-11-01 13:15:14.000,2010-11-01 13:59:03.830,34.0918,-77.9002,,28774,barthur@fubar.com
23594,Travel,Begin,00100227980,2010-11-01 13:15:14.000,2010-11-01 13:59:03.893,34.1594,-77.8929,,28774,barthur@fubar.com
23595,Travel,Begin,00100227980,2010-11-01 13:15:14.000,2010-11-01 13:59:03.940,34.1594,-77.8929,,28774,barthur@fubar.com
23596,Travel,Begin,00100227980,2010-11-01 13:15:14.000,2010-11-01 13:59:15.880,34.1594,-77.8929,,28774,barthur@fubar.com
23597,Travel,Begin,00100227980,2010-11-01 13:15:14.000,2010-11-01 13:59:15.927,34.2743,-77.8668,,28774,barthur@fubar.com
23598,Travel,Begin,00100227980,2010-11-01 13:15:14.000,2010-11-01 13:59:15.987,34.2743,-77.8668,,28774,barthur@fubar.com
23599,Travel,Begin,00100228166,2010-11-01 14:00:13.000,2010-11-01 14:29:45.320,35.0634,-80.7668,,18779,creneau@fubar.com
23600,Travel,End,00100227980,2010-11-01 15:15:58.000,2010-11-01 15:15:40.403,35.3414,-78.0325,,28880,barthur@fubar.com
23601,Travel,Begin,00100228205,2010-11-01 15:30:46.000,2010-11-01 15:41:41.810,35.0661,-80.8376,,18781,creneau@fubar.com
23602,OnSite,Begin,00100227980,2010-11-01 15:15:23.000,2010-11-01 15:59:45.203,35.3873,-77.9395,,28880,barthur@fubar.com
23603,OnSite,End,00100227980,2010-11-01 16:15:22.000,2010-11-01 16:06:09.150,35.3873,-77.9395,,28880,barthur@fubar.com
23604,Travel,Begin,00100228007,2010-11-01 16:15:15.000,2010-11-01 16:15:25.253,35.3873,-77.9395,,28880,barthur@fubar.com
23605,Travel,Begin,,2010-11-01 16:15:12.000,2010-11-01 16:20:49.933,35.0445,-80.8227,Return trip home,18785,creneau@fubar.com
23606,Travel,End,00100228007,2010-11-01 16:30:48.000,2010-11-01 16:26:43.360,35.3873,-77.9395,,28884,barthur@fubar.com
23607,Travel,End,,2010-11-01 17:30:14.000,2010-11-01 17:23:57.897,35.2724,-81.1577,Return trip home,18822,creneau@fubar.com
23608,OnSite,Begin,00100228007,2010-11-01 16:30:48.000,2010-11-01 18:38:32.700,35.3941,-77.994,,28880,barthur@fubar.com
23609,Travel,Begin,00100228209,2010-11-01 17:45:16.000,2010-11-01 18:39:05.683,35.3941,-77.994,,28884,barthur@fubar.com
23610,OnSite,End,00100228007,2010-11-01 17:45:52.000,2010-11-01 18:41:36.980,35.3941,-77.994,,28884,barthur@fubar.com
23611,OnSite,Begin,00100228209,2010-11-01 18:00:38.000,2010-11-01 18:42:12.763,35.3941,-77.994,,28888,barthur@fubar.com
23612,OnSite,End,00100228209,2010-11-01 18:30:44.000,2010-11-01 18:43:29.123,35.3941,-77.994,,28888,barthur@fubar.com
23613,Standby,Begin,,2010-11-01 18:30:58.000,2010-11-01 18:45:28.857,35.3941,-77.994,#1157 ergo,28888,barthur@fubar.com
23614,Standby,End,,2010-11-01 18:45:26.000,2010-11-01 18:46:01.167,35.3941,-77.994,#1157 ergo redo,28888,barthur@fubar.com
23615,Travel,Begin,,2010-11-01 18:45:24.000,2010-11-01 18:47:37.803,35.3941,-77.994,RTN,28888,barthur@fubar.com
23616,Travel,End,,2010-11-01 20:45:05.000,2010-11-01 20:34:39.433,34.139,-77.895,#1142 Fueled,28990,barthur@fubar.com
```

In this image you see that the highlighted rows are showing 6 end times with the same begin times. and records 14 and 15 show 2 begins and no ends.
[image]

Comment: _The problem is that I have duplicate entries were the entry should be marked as having no mate._ Are these exact duplicates? If not, what defines a duplicate? How do we know which begin and end records to match, and which to mark as mateless?

Comment: A duplicate is anytime a begin or end record is reported more than once. in the image 9-13 are dupes as 23583 has already been reported. So 9-13 should be ends without a matching begin. Like 14 and 15 are begins without ends.

Comment: @JoeJohnston, could you possibly update the "DATA" section to include id and correct dates (all dates look like times w/o hours)?  Records corresponding to your output image would be most helpful.

Comment: Or create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model.

Comment: @TimLehner Updated to a more complete schema.

Comment: So you want to find the end-record that is closest to a given begin record, but not after any other record of any type?  -----  Or is it posible to have a situation like this: Begin-Travel, Begin-Standby, End-Travel, End-Standby?    -----  Also, as bluefeet mentioned, a SqlFiddle or at least working insert statements for the data would be very helpful.

Comment: Does this mean you want to omit rows 9-13? and row 15? if yest what EndTime and EndID do you want to reflect?

Comment: 9-13 should be marked incomplete like 15. I need to report them too. If there is an end time without a begin it should be marked as incomplete as well.

Comment: Is the problem solved?
If not could you clarify in your post what you expect, and what is unwanted?
The sentence: "In this image you see that the highlighted rows are showing 6 end times with the same begin times. and records 14 and 15 show 2 begins and no ends." does not help because the information if the display is intended or wrong is missing.

Comment: Back to work from hurricane Sandy. Reviewing answers now. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method which abuses the row_number function.  Please check the comments for some explanation.

```
;with Seq as (
    -- Create a master sequence of events
    -- Trust the date column to be accurate (don't match a Begin to an earlier End)
    select id, activitytype, beginend
        , coalesce(businesskey, '') as businesskey -- Needed to match nulls as equal
        , [date], technician, note
        , row_number() over (partition by technician, businesskey, activitytype order by [date], beginend, id) as rownumber
    from TimeEntry
)
select b.id as BeginID
    , e.id as EndID
    , coalesce(b.technician, e.technician) as Technician
    , coalesce(b.businesskey, e.businesskey) as BusinessKey
    , coalesce(b.activitytype, e.activitytype) as ActivityType
    , coalesce(convert(char(10), b.[date], 103), 'Incomplete') as BeginDate
    , coalesce(convert(char(10), e.[date], 103), 'Incomplete') as EndDate
    , coalesce(convert(char(5), b.[date], 108), 'Incomplete') as BeginTime
    , coalesce(convert(char(5), e.[date], 108), 'Incomplete') as EndTime
    , b.note as BeginNote
    , e.note as EndNote
from (select * from Seq where beginend = 'Begin') b -- Get all Begins
    full outer join (select * from Seq where beginend = 'End') e -- Get all Ends
        on b.technician = e.technician
            and b.businesskey = e.businesskey
            and b.activitytype = e.activitytype
            and b.rownumber = e.rownumber - 1 -- Match a Begin with only the very next End of that type
order by coalesce(b.[date], e.[date])
    , coalesce(b.id, e.id)
    , coalesce(b.technician, e.technician)
    , coalesce(b.businesskey, e.businesskey)
    , coalesce(b.activitytype, e.activitytype)
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fc2b/1) should anyone want the DDL or demo.

Comment: Both of these answers work swimmingly. Tim all things being equal you were first to answer and your code is about 20 lines shorter but you are also >3K rep I would like award the bounty to Steve /if/ its OK with you.

Comment: It's all good, as they say.  I'm glad the ranking concept worked for you.

Comment: Another take away: After seeing SQLfiddle in action. I will make that part of any data question I ask from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE's and Row_Number() I think I can return what you are looking for. The key is to only perform your full outer by joining on adajacent rows based upon an ordering of technician, businesskey, activitytype. Anyway here it is:

```
WITH EventsCTE
AS
(
    select id, technician,businessKey,activityType, 
             CAST(date as date) As date, dateSubmitted,    
             beginEnd, note,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
               (Partition BY technician, 
                businesskey, activityType 
                 ORDER BY dateSubmitted) as rowN
    from TimeEntry
),
BeginEventsCTE
AS
(
    select id, technician,businessKey,activityType, 
             CAST(date as date) As date, 
             dateSubmitted, note, rowN
      from EventsCTE
      WHERE beginEnd = 'Begin'
),
EndEventsCTE
AS
(
    select id, technician,businessKey,
             activityType, CAST(date as date) As date, 
             dateSubmitted, note, rowN
    from EventsCTE
    WHERE beginEnd = 'End'
)
SELECT  B.id, 
        E.id As EndId, 
    COALESCE(B.activityType ,E.activityType ,'Not Available') AS ActivityType,
    COALESCE(convert(VARCHAR(12), B.[date], 103), 'Incomplete') As EventDate, 
    COALESCE(convert(VARCHAR(12), E.[date], 103), 'Incomplete') As EndDate,
    COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5) , B.dateSubmitted , 108) , 'Incomplete') As StartTime, 
    COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5) , E.dateSubmitted , 108) , 'Incomplete') As EndTime, 
    COALESCE(B.Note, E.note, '') as Note, 
    COALESCE(B.technician, E.technician, 'Not Available') As Technician --, B.rowN, E.rowN
 FROM BeginEventsCTE B
 FULL OUTER join EndEventsCTE E
    ON B.technician = E.technician AND
       B.businessKey = E.businessKey AND
       B.activityType = E.activityType AND
       B.date = E.date AND
       B.rowN = E.rowN - 1
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(B.Technician, E.Technician),
    COALESCE(b.id,E.id)
```

And here's the results:

[image: query results]

Comment: Virtually the same thing at the same time, awesomeness!

Comment: Tim, that's just totally bizarre. Get with those ROW_NUMBER()'s everyone