# SQL how to identify first time and last time from a day timestamp records

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm building a Time and Attendance module.

The process starts by importing a Timesheet employee file.

The **Timesheet** employee file has the following columns (red circle show time records from the same employee)

[image]

The **Sensor** column let us know if is an Entrance Sensor (**ENT**) or Exit Sensor (**EXT**)

That information is loaded in a temp table in my SQL Database. My employee table has a RFID_Card column so I can match from the timesheet imported data.

Then, I have to run a Stored Procedure where I can insert into my "employee_timerecord" table every timerecord. The table looks like:

[image]

- EmployeeId (KEY): The employee id (from employee table)
- TimeStamp (KEY):    The timestamp record (datetime) from my imported data
- SensorType (BOOL):  0 = ENTRANCE, 1 = EXIT
- TimeStamp_Type (TINYINT): 1 = First Day Entrance, 2 = Last Day Entrance, 3 = Between Work Hours, 4 = .... etc

My Stored Procedure SQL Script should look something like:

```
INSERT INTO employee_timerecord (employeeid, timestamp,sensortype,timestamp_type)

        SELECT 
        em.employeeid,
        tsi.timestamp,
        s.sensortype, -- 0 = Entrance, 1 = Exit

        --HERE I HAVE TO CHECK IF THE TIME RECORD FOR THAT EMPLOYEE 
    --IS THE FIRST ENTRANCE IN THE DAY THEN ASSING A 1, IF ITS THE LAST 
    --EXIT IN THE DAY THEN ASSIGN A 2, etc

        FROM timesheet_import_temp tsi
        JOIN sensor s ON s.sensorcode = tsi.sensorcode
        JOIN employee em ON em.rfidcard = tsi.rfidcard
```

So from the sample table above, I should get that:

```
Employee with RFID 76:23146: the first timestamp in the day was at: 01/04/2014 06:57:40 a. m.

Employee with RFID 76:23146: the last timestamp in the day was at: 01/04/2014  15:04:48 p. m.
```

Any clue?

Comment: do employees work overnight or can you assume the employee will enter and leave in the same day?

Comment: There are some employees (depending on their shift) that exacly will work overnight. :) seems that you really know about Time and Attendance. Thanks

Comment: @VAAA Does what I proposed works for you? It should if you do not deal with overnight shifts.

Comment: I think it works, but what about overnight shifts, is that going to be complicated to deal with right?

Comment: @VAAA Well, it's not that much complicated. You would have to decide how much elapsed time you can have between two entries before you consider them different shifts.

Comment: @plalx ok, i will try to find on google if there is something I can look at. I will try your code later... re-installing SQL server

Comment: I agree with @plax on the max time issue. I think your issue is much simpler than m original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? Here we choose a maximum period of time between entries that allows us to group them in blocks (shifts). That means we aren't really thinking about *days* anymore but in terms of shifts. Therefore, this shows how you could get the first entry of a shift. Note that it doesn't stop you from knowing on which day the shift started either.

*Note: The code is not tested*

```
-- Helps creating entries blocks
DECLARE @maxHoursBetweenEntries int = 4;

CASE
    WHEN (
        SELECT MIN(timestamp)
        FROM timesheet_import_temp tsi1
        WHERE 
            rfidcard = tsi.rfidcard
            AND sensortype = 0
            AND ISNULL(DATEDIFF(
              hour,
              (
                  SELECT MAX(timestamp)
                  FROM timesheet_import_temp
                  WHERE
                      AND rficard = tsi1.rficard
                      AND timestamp < tsi1.timestamp
                      AND sensortype = 1
              ),
              timestamp
            ), maxHoursBetweenEntries) >= @maxHoursBetweenEntries
    ) = tsi.timestamp THEN 1
    ...
END
```

Comment: That maximum elapsed time calculation can be done in the same CASE?

Comment: @VAAA I modified the answer accordingly. Is this what you meant? I haven't tested but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Ohh sounds nice, yest the time max between entries will be 8 hours because there are only 3 shifts... I will try the code later and let you know. I really appreciate it @plalx

Answer (score 0):

I did a very similar thing a while back.

You will need to create an assumption of first or last count for example lines 3 and 4 in your data.

I am making a sql fiddle for you now.

[T-SQL join to get both mated and non mated start and stop records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963293/t-sql-join-to-get-both-mated-and-non-mated-start-and-stop-records)

Comment: appreaciate so much your help really. This Time and Attendance stuff and rules seems not too easy, and I have a dead line of 2 months to have this module up and running :(

Comment: OK! I see you need only first and last. Yes?

Comment: Yes, well later I will have to deal with Overnight shifts that for sure will be a pain in the neck.

Comment: OK, I am trying to get this done now. Have to leave soon for family stuff but working it. Duplicating your data. Do you have a script for the table and some data?

Comment: I just have the script for my timestamp temp table. Really appreciate it

Comment: After creating the data I think your solve is the code @plalx offered.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joe, however i will have to think how to deal with Overnight shifts :(

Comment: @JoeJohnston Have a look at my answer if you are interested to see how I dealt with shifts spanning on multiple days.

Comment: @plalx I will check it out more tools in the toolbox! In my case they were not allowed to go past midnight. I have since fixed the data structure on that gig and now there is one row created on start and then updated on stop. Mo Bettah!